# Is there any benefit to equipping the Range Finder on a Sniper Rifle?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I just located the Range Finder part and decided to try it out on my sniper rifle (specifically the SR25).  Does the Range Finder give me any weapon action such as 'zero-ing' a target through my scope?  There are no new functions added to my DPAD while I am zoomed in.  Does this part just boost accuracy and range stats?  As my SR25 accuracy and range stats are already maxed, is there any benefit to equipping this part with this sniper rifle?

Comment: There is bullet drop in the game, so you might be able to use that.  In Battlefield 4, I loved the range finder for this reason.

Comment: Also, if you are going for the achievement for getting a sniper kill at over 400m+ away, this will come in handy - as I found out last night!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, there really *isn't* a benefit to attaching a Range Finder to a sniper rifle aside from increasing the Range stat. If your Range stat is maxed as you said it is, then it appears that attaching the Range Finder would give you no benefit. From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168639-tom-clancys-ghost-recon-wildlands/75091677):

> I was wondering the samething, then I just figured it was for stat boosting.

And from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wildlands/comments/5y6ymy/rangefinder/):

> It adds range to the gun. It doesn't give you range to target in any way.

In that same thread, it seems that the Range Finder doesn't even help you if you play without a HUD (as many people thought it might)

> User 1: Yea I have no HUD on my game and was aiming towards the range finder for my overwatch position. Hope it's actually beneficial
>
> User 2: It does nothing than effect the stats of the gun. [...] I was disapointed as well.